# iOS - Select a number randomly

Tags: ios, objective-c, random

I am trying to select a random number for x position , but I have an issue with random method  , here is my code :

```
        int xPosition = [self placeRandomEnemy];
        car3.position = CGPointMake(xPosition, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
```

// random method :

```
- (int)placeRandomEnemy {

    int x1 = 60;

    int x2 = 160 ;

    int x3 = 260;

  return arc4random() %  (x1 , x2 , x3);

}
```

`xPosition`  should be a number from x1 or x2 or x3 , but my method doesn't work .

Comment: "xPosition should be a number from x1 or x2 or x3" -- What makes you say that??

Comment: (What you coded is equivalent to `return arc4random() % 260;`.  Look up the "comma operator".  And look up "modulus operator".)

Comment: @HotLicks I think he needs random % 3 to be used as an index into an array that holds `x1`, `x2`, and `x3` based on my read of the question...

Comment: @nhgrif - I'd say that's fairly far down on his list of needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `return arc4random() %  (x1 , x2 , x3);`
with

```
switch (arc4random_uniform(3)) {
        case 0:
            return x1;
            break;
        case 1:
            return x2;
            break;
        default:
            return x3;
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int placeRandomEnemey() {
    static int xPos[] = { 60, 160, 260 };
    return xPos[arc4random_uniform(sizeof(xPos) / sizeof(xPos[0]))];
}
```

This will return `60`, `160`, `260`.

---

And it can be used as such:

```
car3.position = CGPointMake(placeRandomEnemy(), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take these values in array and then you can get random index like this way.

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];


int rand= arc4random()%[arr count];
NSLog(@"%d",rand);
```

Now you can get value of object `at random` index.

```
int value = [[arr objectAtIndex:rand] intValue];
```

This is simple solution.

There may be different methods to get it.

Comment: Why would you put `NSString` objects in the array and not `NSNumber`?